# Divinity Original Sin: Would the 2nd player be able to play using a second USB keyboard?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

So my brother and I are thinking of buying Divinity Orignal Sin: Enhanced Edition as it seems like an enjoyable co op game. I've seen the option for split screen in some walk through, and I've noticed that the second player uses a game controller.

I can't afford a game controller at the moment, so I was wondering if we would be able to play split screen using a second keyboard for my brother. Would that work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to adeveloper in [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/373420/discussions/0/405691491107079826/) thread

> Local co-op is only available when using 2 controllers (there were UI
>   issues when KB/mouse + controller was tested during development).

Seems the only solution might be a controller, but xbox gamepads may be affordable if found second-hand. [This](https://steamcommunity.com/app/373420/discussions/0/490124466474590073/) thread claims:

> Yeah, sadly the way they coded it, a controller plugged in seems to
>   take over for P1, then a second controller plugged in acts as P2.
>   Console controls aren't too bad, at least.

So it seems two controllers are needed.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it's the case though